# Pulling out a broken spring wire from an electrical conduit

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I want to install an fiberoptic drop cable in a 1/2" conduit with an existing phone line. The other side of the conduit is approximately 20m away in the utility duct of my apartment.

Found a broken spring wire in the opening inside the apartment and I'm unable to pull it out with pliers.

Two electricians have given up pulling it out. Appreciate any new ideas.

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit] to add a picture? I'm unclear what sort of "spring wire" you might have encountered - possibly a broken fish tape? Mind you, if you and two electricians have not been able to budge it, it may require replacing the conduit to actually fix the issue.

Comment: Can you provide us with photos of this conduit?

Comment: It might be a fish tape that got snagged and someone gave up and cut it off. Will it push in at all? You may be able to solder an extension on it and push it through the other way.

Comment: The "wire" is inside the conduit. I felt it with my finger and pulled it out a bit with a lot of effort. Then used a plier to pull more of it but after some point it retracted back into the conduit. Too tired to pull it out so will definitely click a photo when I do.

Comment: It looks similar to this one https://images.app.goo.gl/CseYrqDjcUFUo93ZA

Comment: So far I have drained around a litre of dishwasher soap and water into it.

Comment: @isherwood likely. Will try with a vacuum and blower but I doubt that it will work.

Comment: Without seeing the actual spring in question, I would suggest that you may need to rotate it to unhook it from whatever it's grabbed. Might also be helpful to see if the telephone line in place appears to get tight at the opposite end when you try to pull the spring out. If so you might be able to unhook that and pull them both out, then pull in a new telephone wire (or the same one if it's not damaged significantly, but I'd plan for new unless you don't use it) and the fiber-optic drop.

Comment: Bang on the EMT while some else pulls it. W/o permission to tear down drywall to get to the fittings to bang on or disconnect them, you could be SoL. You're risking damaging the phone line, but you could attach a fish tape to what you can pull out and then try to push it in so that it unhooks. The objective is to install a fiber line; consider this conduit defunct and run it somewhere else.